# I want to take a generate number between 1 to 5 in batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, random, cmd, command-line

I want to generate a random number between 1 to 5 in a batch file

Answer (score 1):

Since it's tagged PowerShell:

```
Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5
```

Or

```
[System.Random]::new().Next( 1, 5 )
```

If you want to run inside a batch file you can just execute PowerShell with the `-Command` parameter:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5"
```

You can use either method with this syntax

Answer (score 0):

Using batch, syntax is (`set /a var=(%RANDOM%*max/32768)+min`)

```
@echo off
set /a rand=(%RANDOM%*5/32768)+1
echo %rand%
```

Comment: `set /a rand=(%RANDOM% %% max)+min` actually gets you a more even distribution of random numbers

Comment: Also worth noting Delayed expansion and !random! should be used if generating the random number within a code block.